# How can I prevent the webpage from scrolling back to the top when I use slideup?

Tags: jquery, scroll, slideup

I have a webpage with multiple DIV elements. If i use the jquery function SlideUp to hide one (which is towards the bottom of the page), the page automatically scrolls back to the top. How can I prevent this?

To trigger the jquery function, I do something like this:

```
$(MyLink).click(function() {
MyDiv.slideUp("slow");
}
```

`MyLink` being within `MyDiv` which is somewhere in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was what someone suggested (adding `return false`) and it worked:

```
$(MyLink).click(function() {
MyDiv.slideUp("slow");
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

How do you trigger the jquery function, via anchors? If so, have the function return false, otherwise the browser will redirect to the href-attribute, which would be '#' in this case.

Comment: To trigger the jquery function, I do something like this:
$(MyLink).click(function() {MyDiv.SlideUp}  
MyLink being within MyDiv